# Magento 2 : Get product price by sales_order_item table

Tags: magento2

How can I get product **price** by `sales_order_item` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject the order Model in your constructor

```
protected $orderModel;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderModel,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->orderModel = $orderModel;
    ....
}
```

Then use this method as:

```
$order = $this->orderModel->load($orderId); //Add your order ID
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    echo $item->getPrice()."<br>";
}
```

This worked for me. Hope it also works for you.

Comment: This returns null for me

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please check